# Visual Studio Advanced Query Builder MySql adding “def.” before the table names

Tags: asp.net, sql, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to create dataset (.xsd) and link it with stored procedure in MySQL database.

the problem is when i connect it it's changing the schema name.

like if I have this stored procedure name or table name or whatever  :

News.tbNews

the builder it self change it to :

def.News.tbNews.
MySql version 5.5.8, MySqlConnector 6.3.4
I searched for a solution for this problem and one of the answers was to change the MySqlConnector from 6.3.4 to 6.3.6 !!!

I download the new connector  6.3.6 but it's giving me Error while installing it.

any Idea People ???

thanks and best regards.

Comment: all what you have to do is :

1- install framework 4.0 before installing the .net connector 6.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ,the problem is solved now

all what you have to do is : 1- install framework 4.0 before installing the .net connector 6.3.6